# "declare" works with sqlplus and sql developer but why not with sql navigator?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sql-navigator

I tried to declare/initialize variables on sqlplus and sql developer and it worked.
But when I copy/paste the same code and execute on sql navigator it doesnt work.
Could you tell me why and what I need to change so it works also on sql navigator?

```
variable g_firstname varchar2(30)
variable g_lastname varchar2(30)
declare
v_firstname varchar2(30);
v_lastname varchar2(30);
begin
v_firstname := 'Tony';
v_lastname := 'Stark';
:g_firstname := v_firstname;
:g_lastname := v_lastname;
end;
/
print g_firstname g_lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `declare`, but `variable`.

SQL Plus is Oracle's command line tool that allows you to access an Oracle database. SQL Developer is Oracle's GUI tool; as such, it is capable of running number of SQL Plus commands.

However, that's not the case with other tools - they work well with pure SQL or PL/SQL, but **not** with SQL*Plus commands.

Therefore, remove the first two lines and execute the rest. It *should* work, though - not the way you'd want it to.